# How to simplify my expression to the style of "a+b*I"?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

**How to simplify my expression to the style of "a+b*I"?**

```
Expand[(E^(I θ) (-1 + E^(I n θ)))/(-1 + E^(I θ))]
```

> ```
> -(E^(I θ)/(-1 + E^(I θ))) + E^(I θ + I n θ)/(-1 + E^(I θ))
> ```

[image: the result I want to achieve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown by others, you are looking for a combination of [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComplexExpand.html) and [`Collect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Collect.html).  In your case, `ComplexExpand` does a good job of separating the real and imaginary components of your expression.

[image]

In general, you will end up with a number of terms, and you will need to use `Collect` to merge them together.  However, using `Collect` on `I` does not usually work

```
Collect[a I + (1 + I) b, I]
(* I a + (1 + I) b *)
```

because `I` is interpreted as `Complex[0, 1]`, so `Collect` will not break up numbers like `1 + I`. So, the most effective method I have found is to replace `I` with some other symbol, like `q`.

```
Block[{q}, 
  Collect[
   ComplexExpand[expr] /. Complex[a_, b_] :> a + q b, 
   q, Simplify
  ] /. q -> I
]
(*
    Cos[1/2 (1 + n) θ] Csc[θ/2] Sin[(n θ)/2] 
+ I Csc[θ/2] Sin[(n θ)/2] Sin[1/2 (1 + n) θ]
*)
```

where `expr` is your expression.  Note I set the third argument of `Collect` to `Simplify` which reduced the complexity of the real and imaginary parts quite well.

Answer (score 3):

I hope this is what you need:

```
Collect[Expand[(E^(I \[Theta]) (-1 + E^(I n \[Theta])))/(-1 + 
      E^(I \[Theta]))] // ComplexExpand, I]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
exp = Expand[(E^(I \[Theta]) (-1 + E^(I n \[Theta])))/(-1 +E^(I \[Theta]))]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
r = Simplify@ComplexExpand@Re@exp + I*Simplify@ComplexExpand@Im@exp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

it is now in the form `a+I b`

```
{a, b} = First@Cases[r, Plus[a_, I b_] :> {a, b}, {0}];
a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
b
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]