# Express a complex function $f(z)$ as $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

Tags: complex

How can I write a complex function $f(z)$ in the form $u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ using Mathematica? Re and Im do not work, because they do it for complex numbers, not functions.
For example, if I try

```
Re[2 I (z) + 6 Conjugate[(z)] + Sin[(z)]]
```

Mathematica returns:

```
-2 Im[z] + 6 Re[z] + Re[Sin[z]]
```

Comment: Previously: [Extract real part of a complex expression better than Re does](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3306/484), [Does the Im function work with symbolic arguments?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4973/484), [How to simplify my expression to the style of “a+b*I”?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/32170/484). I probably should have searched for duplicates before posting my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `z` with `x + I y` and use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html).

```
ComplexExpand[2 I z + 6 Conjugate[z] + Sin[z] /. z -> x + I y]
(* 6 x - 2 y + Cosh[y] Sin[x] + I (2 x - 6 y + Cos[x] Sinh[y]) *)
```