# Simplifying complex fractions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

How can I simplify a complex fraction in order to get something of the shape

```
(a + I b)/(c + I d)?
```

Note that I would not like Mathematica to further simplify it by multiplying both sides by c - I d.

For example:

```
R1 + 1/(I w C1 + 1/(R2 + 1/(I w C2)))
```

When I //Simplify it, only the lower fraction gets simplified. I obtain

> R1 + 1/(I C1 w + (C2 w)/(-I + C2 R2 w))

When //Apart

> R1 - I/((C1 + C2) w) - (
>    I C2^2 R2)/((C1 + C2) (-I C1 - I C2 + C1 C2 R2 w))

//ComplexExpand separates the whole expression in real and imaginary parts, as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [(32170)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32170/how-to-simplify-my-expression-to-the-style-of-abi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
expr = R1 + 1/(I w C1 + 1/(R2 + 1/(I w C2))) //. {I -> i, -I -> -i}
Collect[Numerator@#, i]/Collect[Denominator@#, i] /. {i^2 -> -1, i -> I} &@Factor@expr
```

results in

```
(C1 R1 w + C2 R1 w + C2 R2 w + I (-1 + C1 C2 R1 R2 w^2))/(C1 w + C2 w + I C1 C2 R2 w^2)
```

See [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32170/how-to-simplify-my-expression-to-the-style-of-abi) for some comments about simplifying expressions involving `I`.

Answer (score 0):

```
expr = R1 + 1/(I w C1 + 1/(R2 + 1/(I w C2)));
```

`Map` either `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` onto the real and imaginary components of the expression. They are then treated separately.

```
Simplify /@ ComplexExpand[expr]

(*  R1 + (C2^2*R2)/(2*C1*C2 + C2^2 + 
        C1^2*(1 + C2^2*R2^2*w^2)) - 
   (I*(C1 + C2 + C1*C2^2*R2^2*w^2))/
     (w*(2*C1*C2 + C2^2 + 
           C1^2*(1 + C2^2*R2^2*w^2)))  *)

FullSimplify /@ ComplexExpand[expr, Element[var, Reals]]

(*  R1 + (C2^2*R2)/((C1 + C2)^2 + 
        C1^2*C2^2*R2^2*w^2) - 
   (I*(C1 + C2 + C1*C2^2*R2^2*w^2))/
     ((C1 + C2)^2*w + C1^2*C2^2*R2^2*
          w^3)  *)
```